# How to use conditional formatting in excel for a crosstabbed table with multiple conditions?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I am having trouble in excel using conditional formatting for my table. I need to highlight the sample values that are greater than screening_1 or screening_2 for each individual row.If the value is greater than screening_1 I would like the sample values highlighted green, and if the value is greater than screening_2 I would like the sample values highlighted blue. I would also like to exclude highlighting on values where the screening values are blank.I have attached an example of what the table looks like (dummy data) and how I'd like the conditional formatting to be. Thank you!

[image: Table before and after example]

Comment: This seems straightforward enough, what have you tried?

Comment: The logic you explained is incomplete and the example image is not clear.  For example, in row "Chemical_2", `Sample_1 is greater than Screening_1 and also greater than Screening_2` and colored **green**, but in row "Chemical_3", `Sample_4 is greater than Screening_1 and also greater than Screening_2`, but it is colored **blue**.

Answer (score 0):

Iagree with Blind Spots, please choose one a priority among them (greater than Screening_1 and also greater than Screening_2).

But if you want it depends on the maximum of both of Screening_1 and Screening_2, you may try following condition formulas.

[image]

Green:

`=IF(AND($B2<>"",E2>$B2,E2<$C2,MAX($B2,$C2)=$C2),1,0)`

`=IF(AND($B2<>"",E2>$B2,MAX($B2,$C2)=$B2),1,0)`

Blue:

`=IF(AND($C2<>"",E2>$C2,E2<$B2,MAX($B2,$C2)=$B2),1,0)`

`=IF(AND($C2<>"",E2>$C2,MAX($B2,$C2)=$C2),1,0)`